# How can I build a LEGO heart?

Tags: building

In the spirit of Valentine's Day...

How can I build a two-dimensional LEGO heart? [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Heart_coraz%C3%B3n.svg) is an example of the shape I'm looking for.

Perhaps the model should be built from the bottom upward? I would prefer that some [Red Slope 45° 2 x 2](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=3496-1) bricks (and their inverted counterparts) be used to achieve this.

[image: Red Slope 45° 2 x 2]

The size of the finished model should not be much bigger than one's hand.

Comment: Feel free to add or change tags as appropriate; I wasn't sure which ones would be best. Additionally, the first link is to Wikipedia: go ahead and switch that for the image listed there if it would be easier to read.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you live near a LEGO store you might have enough time to pick up the seasonal Valentines set [40004-1: Heart](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=40004-1):

[image]

If you're short on parts, you can build a basic heart out of 2x2 and 2x4 bricks for a truly brick-style:

[image]

You can always smooth out the edges with red 2x2 sloped tiles and a few cheese slopes:

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Super simple one:[image]

Comment: .........clever

Comment: That is probably the only heart necklace I'd ever wear. :)

Answer (score 6):

I came up with the following design:

[image]

Using the following parts:

1x [part:2341:4]
2x [part:2449:4]
1x [part:3005:4]
2x [part:3024:4]
2x [part:3040:4]
1x [part:3070b:4]
3x [part:3622:4]
2x [part:3623:4]
2x [part:3665:4]
2x [part:54200:4]

Comment: ♥ You could swap the four cheese slopes (54200) for two 2x1 double-sided slopes [(3044)](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3044) ♥

Comment: True, although I liked the subtle change in angle the cheese slopes give, with a slightly more rounded top.